# error AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name

Tags: macos, apache

when i try to do sudo apachectl start

it return this error

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Dava-Erandas-MacBook-Pro.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

what i've done is

adding a line containing ServerName 127.0.0.1 in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

base on this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-configuration-error-ah00558-could-not-reliably-determine-the-server-s-fully-qualified-domain-name

but it still returning the same error.

what should i do to get rid of this error?

Comment: "127.0.0.1" does not sound like a particularly fully qualified _domain_ name. Plus, it'd depend on where you configure it. Also, this actually ir rather a warning or informative message than an error.

Comment: what should i write instead of 127.0.0.1, because it's what the tutorial said. i'm stuck in this error, i need to make my Sites Folder can be accessed through localhost/~username/websiteFolder

Comment: @DavaEranda Then it should be `ServerName localhost`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem in the comment section of the top rated answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280099/apache-on-macos-sierra-ah00557-httpd-apr-sockaddr-info-get-failed-for-macbo)
I had 2 installations of apache, the one that came with the system and the one I installed using `brew install httpd`
Error disappeared when I run `brew uninstall httpd`